# Lumen Global Middleware not working if registered outside bootstrap/app.php

Tags: php, laravel, web-services, laravel-5.3, lumen

I wrote a custom Lumen package (specifically for users management). It works fine. However, when I tried adding a global middleware and registered it from within the package itself, it doesn't gets called (see below).

**vendor/something/src/UserServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot() {
    $this->app->middleware([
        SomeMiddleware::class
    ]);
}
```

**vendor/something/src/Middlewares/SomeMiddleware.php**

```
class SomeMiddleware {
    public function handle(Request $request, \Closure $next) {
        exit('here'); // this was never called
    }
}
```

**bootstrap/app.php**

```
$app->register(\Something\UserServiceProvider::class);
```

---

However, when I tried registering it in *bootstrap/app.php* instead inside the *UserServiceProvider.php* class, it works fine.

**bootstrap/app.php**

```
// $app->register(\Something\UserServiceProvider::class);
// ...
$app->middleware([SomeMiddleware::class]);
```

Any advice?

Comment: If it's a global middleware, you shouldn't need to key the array so you could probably remove the `'myapp.something' => ` portion.  Also make sure you are registering the service provider as well.

Comment: Thanks man. Yes. I tried removing that portion as well but to no luck. I also confirmed that I registered the service provider properly.